# How to install TeX Live offline on Ubuntu?

Tags: texlive, installing, offline

My laptop is running Ubuntu 14.04.
I am trying to install "vanilla" TeX Live,
following the instructions found in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/7142).

Unfortunately, it seems to take a very long time (~18 hours)
to download all of the packages.

```
$ sudo ./install-tl
...
Installing [0345/3406, time/total: 01:55:31/17:46:13]: biblatex-phys [411k]
Installing [0346/3406, time/total: 01:56:03/17:49:26]: biblatex-publist [308k]
Installing [0347/3406, time/total: 01:56:05/17:48:28]: biblatex-realauthor [94k]
Installing [0348/3406, time/total: 01:56:36/17:52:50]: biblatex-sbl [699k]
Installing [0349/3406, time/total: 01:56:38/17:50:15]: biblatex-science [368k]
Installing [0350/3406, time/total: 01:57:10/17:53:37]: biblatex-shortfields [82k]
Installing [0351/3406, time/total: 01:57:11/17:53:26]: biblatex-source-division [66k]
...
```

I'm quite surprised that it takes such a long time
to download all of the packages.
Is there a way to speed up the process by installing from an offline file
which contains all of the packages inside?

I do have access to a computer in my office,
which could probably download the packages more quickly
because it has a wired Internet connection
as opposed to my laptop's wireless Internet connection.

Comment: There is an ISO image of TeX Live available: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html

Comment: Members of TUG or DANTE get a free TL DVD soon after its release (hint: Become a member either of TUG or DANTE ) ;-)

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by Biki Teron and DG',
it is possible to download an ISO file `texlive2016.iso`.
I was able to download the file in my office computer,
which took about 30 minutes.

To install TeX Live from the ISO file:

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/iso
$ sudo mount -o loop texlive2016.iso /media/iso/
$ cd /media/iso
$ sudo ./install-tl
...
Installing [0060/3252, time/total: 00:10/10:09]: aichej [7k]
Installing [0061/3252, time/total: 00:10/10:09]: ajl [7k]
Installing [0062/3252, time/total: 00:10/10:09]: akktex [16k]
Installing [0063/3252, time/total: 00:10/10:09]: akletter [208k]
Installing [0064/3252, time/total: 00:10/10:05]: alegreya [4672k]
Installing [0065/3252, time/total: 00:11/09:47]: aleph [31k]
...
```

Notice that the time to install is much faster,
about 10 minutes compared to 18 hours
to install from packages downloaded online.

Comment: But when I installed it using ISO  and sudo ./install-tl, aftert the imstallation is completed. TexStudio don't recognized the texlive installation because I have an error message. I installed using PPA, but it was useful intalling offline from ISO.

Comment: @nandhos You should ask about this as a question, rather than as a comment

Answer (score 3):

You can install Texlive offline by entering this command in your terminal as root "./install-tl -gui perltk" before entering make sure you have install perltk in ubuntu, then GUI installation windows will open for texlive installation. For offline installation go to this page and download the huge iso http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/systems/texlive/Images/texlive2016.iso

Comment: How does this answer the question? `install-tl` still needs a network connection

Comment: we can install offline once we have the ISO file @ChristianHupfer

Comment: Getting the ISO file needs an internet connection as well, unless someone rips an image from an existing DVD